# Integrating Alfresco Flexspaces with JBOSS portal

Tags: apache-flex, portlet, alfresco, jboss-portal

We're working on a development of a JBoss portal. As part of the functionality, we need to integrate it with Alfresco, using a portlet. Both (portal and Alfresco) will connect to the same LDAP directory to get the users, to guarantee that the same users can access to both systems. Right now that part of the implementation is not completed, so we have created the same users/password on both.

To present the content of Alfresco, we're using a Flexspaces portlet. When the page containing the portlet is loaded, a window appears requesting the login/password on Alfresco. After the login, the browser keeps track of the session.
Then, when the users logs out from the portal, we're experiencing problems, as the portlet is having some problems, like asking login (not on Flex, but on old-fashion javascript way), but not accepting it, and showing errors of "invalid Ticket"

As the portal knows the user that needs to be logged (and when it logs out) on the Alfresco system, what would it be the easiest way to make this integration? How can we communicate to the Flex to make login and logout from the portal?

Also, we're interested in knowing how to communicate from the portal to the flex, not just for this problem, but for further development.

Answer (score 0):

I started a topic on the FlexSpaces forum on the alfresco forge to help you with this:

http://forge.alfresco.com/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1202&forum_id=534